# Fading photos in slideshow using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, animation, slideshow, fading

I have a website, and a slideshow of pictures on the main page. Before a photo is removed, I write the next photo behind it and then remove it. I wanted to know how I can add a fading effect before the photo is removed. my website is: guyzyl.org, so you can check out what im talking about. Also I dont know how to use Jquery, so please dont offer that solution. Thanks for any help. Guy Z.

Comment: i think you shouldn't give up on jquery without trying it. see the example on this site, it is easy to implement and supported across browsers (as Derek's doesn't cover IE's short comings, shame on them not him) http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-fadein-fadeout-and-fadeto-example/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.photo{
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;  /*Webkit*/
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;  /*Firefox*/
    -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;  /*Opera*/
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;  /*CSS3 Standard*/
    opacity: 1;
}
.photo.fade{
    opacity: 0;
}

document.querySelector(".photo").classList.add("fade");
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/jzLZZ/

Comment: but I want it to fade before removing it, not when it is written, so can I edit the photos style before removing it using javascript?

Comment: @guyzyl - See demo if it is what you expected.

Comment: did you test this in IE? doesn't seem to work for either 7, 8, or 9

Comment: can you help me implement this in my website (guyzyl.org)?

Comment: @guyzyl - I recommend you use jQuery for that purpose, since it is easy to use, and most important -- cross browser capable.

Comment: @Derek - I wrote an HTML with your code, and it didn't work. - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25407332/testFade.html - do you know why is that?

Comment: @guyzyl - You put some extra characters in Line 11: `;â€‹` (Maybe it's a problem from changing `ANSI` to `UTF-8`, just delete it)

Comment: @guyzyl See See http://derek1906.site50.net/experiment/testFade.html (fixed for you)

Comment: @Derek - new problem. tried to implament your solution to my website, and it didnt work.  - guyzyl.org/files/slideshow.js -  check the bWrite() function, and thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @guyzyl - I have taken a look in your script. The problem is here: `setTimeout("bWrite", 2000);`; it should be `setTimeout(bWrite, 2000);`.([Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Jaeej)) It also seems that you are trying to put the CSS `transition:` into the `style` part every time, but what really is is that you just need to set it once. And instead of `.style = style + fade;`, you can do `.style += fade;`. Good luck!

Comment: @Derek - sorry to bother you again, but I rewrote the slideshow code again to make it more understandable, and more efficient, but a new problem arose. - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntwsegtyreli2lc/slideshow.js -it works fine, but when I try to zero the opacity to make the fade effect (using document.getElementById('photo').style.opacity = '0';), it screws up the slideshow. i added the fade thing to the css, and you can also see all of the code on my website - guyzyl.org -

Comment: @guyzyl - If I didn't get it wrong, your code is only for doing the slideshow thing, right? And it is over-complicated IMO. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/HxZ3Y/ , I create the slideshow with only 15 lines, and no problems appeared so far. ;)

Comment: @Derek - thanks for the example you wrote, but since Im new to javascript, and Im not really that good, I cant understand what the code does. additionaly, my code is complicated because i dont want to see a white space when the photo changes - so can you help me fix the code I have?

Comment: @guyzyl - Here, no white space showing, 13 lines only (:D), http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/HxZ3Y/3/ (*explanation included*) Also you might want to take a look at the CSS code too.

Comment: @Derek - thank you for the slideshow you wrote, but I would like to keep my code as it is (and also i couldnt implement you slideshow). can you please, just tell me how i can change the opacity to 0 in my gallery, so there is the fade effect?